Cannot access uninitialized variable
I am getting a client-side JavaScript exception in SvelteKit, and nothing is displayed:
Cannot access uninitialized variable.
map@[native code]
@https://44a6-104-255-135-103.ngrok-free.app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/client.js:355:38
get_navigation_result_from_branch@https://44a6-104-255-135-103.ngrok-free.app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/client.js:325:52
@https://44a6-104-255-135-103.ngrok-free.app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/client.js:770:49

The stack trace is unusable.
How to fix?

This error is specific to Safari/Webkit.
SvelteKit fails to render a page during the import stage. This likely means some of your code may import JavaScript modules that are not compatible on the client-side code.

Restore the application codebase to last good known state
Remove the imports that cause issues
If possible try to move problematic imports to dynamic imports during onMount or resort to other such tricks

